# Изменить настройки DataSet

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, oledb

Есть у меня программка на C#, которая тянет данные и пишет в MS SQL. Для этого она использует `DataSet`. Мне необходимо перевести ее на работу с MySQL (при этом структура БД не изменится). Насколько я понимаю, мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы вместо `SqlConnection` появилось `OleDbConnection` и так по всем классам, но если лезть в Desinger.cs ручками, то все изменения слетят, стоит заглянуть в схему (ну или не только заглянуть, а как-то изменить). Выйти на какие-то настройки подключения я не смог. Есть ли способ это сделать без создания нового `DataSet`?